# How can i create a selectbox, with color square symbols on options (bootstrap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-select, font-awesome, pseudo-element

I am simply trying to produce a bootstrap select, with colored squares, representing the option elements' color code. (See fiddle in end, for greyscale example)

My initial thought was to create two tags within the option, one for the color square, and one for the text. However, option tags does not allow for children DOM-elements.

My second though was to use a font-awesome glyph, a square, and then styling the option with the ::first-letter pseudo element selector. That was also unsuccessful. I originally though it was because the option tags were inline elements, as ::first-letter only work on block-elements, but that seems not to be the case. My options are block elements, but a *::first-element selector, only changes the color of my first letters in labels, headings etc.

Since I cannot create fa-icons within the standard -tag in an option, I've used this syntax to display the glyphs:

```
<select class="form-control" id="ActionType" 
    style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Helvetica;">
    <option value="insert">&#xf04d; Insert</option>
    <option value="delete">&#xf04d; Delete</option>
    <option value="update">&#xf04d; Update</option>                             
</select>
```

This uses unicode to reference the glyphs, and it works, except for the fact that I can't get the colors to work. `&#xf04d;` represents the icon `fa-stop`, which is pretty much a square

Here is a JSfiddle, which shows pretty much my desired result, except from the colors. I will accept any answer that can provide a visually similar solution, which works in a bootstrap-setup. I would also need the colors actually working, of course. In this example, I've simplified it, and set `*::first-letter` to `red`.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljxx0str/

Comment: have you tried wrapping them in span class?

Comment: Wrapping what exactly in span classes? the options?

Comment: I am assuming you just need the colored icons, wrap the glyphs

Comment: As I wrote in my question, <option>-tags does not allow children tags.

Comment: All other tags within an option, are simply disregarded. So yeah, I did consider that approach.

Comment: Icons inside options are not a good idea, I was stuck there a while as well, styling the options does not work in all browsers (e.g. Chrome).
If you really need icons, try a javascript/jQuery solution.

Comment: are all the icons the same?

Comment: In this select, yes they are all the same. @AlexG, I am aware that my solution would not work on most browsers on a mac. However, my support specifications are very specific, and only a handful of people, with identical setup, would use the editor that this select is a part of. I do not specifically need Icons. I need a good way of representing colors, and I'd rather not make the whole option a color, i.e. with background-color. I did come up short after a few attempts, but since It feels like I am very close, I figured I could try to ask a question, instead of starting from square one.

Comment: Hey, @AlexG. When you say javascript/jquery solution, do you mean moving away from the standard <select>/<option> and make a custom drop down, i.e. from list elements?

Comment: Yes exactly, I haven't used one yet, but this seems to be a very good plugin: **[jQuery Selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render)**

Comment: I'll have a look at it. I would have to ensure that it follows the same look and feel as bootstrap-selects though, to make the form similar to others, and predictable for it's users :). Thanks anyway. I keep finding more and more evidence that styling (part of) option tags, is no easy task.

Comment: I've been looking at nicer selects, too, recently - and I found [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) which also has a [Bootstrap-Style](http://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/) (under dev, however) - so depending on your case-case this might an interesting alternative (_I like it better because of the Search-Option_)